# How to create a bitmap from html string using CefSharp?

Tags: c#, chromium

I need to create a bitmap from an html string using the **CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser**.

```
var browser = new CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser(htmlString);
// what to do?
var bitmap = browser.Bitmap;
```

What do I have to do to get the bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the URL and not the html string to the ChromiumWebBrowser and waiting for the browser to finish loading the html file solves this problem:

```
var browser = new CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser(htmlURL);

// wait the browser to finish loading the html file   
using (var waitHandle = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false))
{
    EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> loadingHandler = null;
    loadingHandler = (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!e.IsLoading)
        {
            if (browser != null)
            {
                browser.LoadingStateChanged -= loadingHandler;
            }
            waitHandle.Set();
        }
    };

    browser.LoadingStateChanged += loadingHandler;
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
}

var bitmap = browser.Bitmap; // bitmap not null
```

Comment: As a note, CefSharp does not support .net core. This solution is only for .net framework :(